# Progressview tintColorIssue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have created a progressview according to number images as you can see in below code.

```
let view = UIView()
view.backgroundColor = .clear
        
let progressView = UIProgressView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frameOfParentView.width/3 - 8, height: 30))
progressView.progressViewStyle = .default
progressView.progress = 0.0
progressView.tintColor = .red
progressView.trackTintColor = .gray
progressView.layoutIfNeeded()
view.addSubview(progressView)
self.arrayOfProgrssView.append(progressView)
```

As you can see in gif at starting point tintColor alpha is little bit less but when it tense to reach at 100% it is fully red.

I also tried with below code:-

```
progressView.progressTintColor = .red
```

but did not get expected result.

To perform animation,

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.001) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: self.animationInMS) {
        progressView.setProgress(1, animated: true)
    }
}
progressView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Issue in iOS 15:-

[image]

As you see below result with other colour.

[image]

Note:- I have checked in iOS 12.4 it's working properly as you can see into image.

[image]

Please let me know is anything require from my side.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does appear to be "new behavior" where the alpha value matches the percent completion -- although, after some quick searching I haven't found any documentation on it.

One option as a work-around: set the `.progressImage` instead of the tint color.

So, use your favorite code to generate a solid-color image, such as:

```
extension UIImage {
    
    public static func withColor(_ color: UIColor, size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)) -> UIImage {
        let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
        format.scale = 1
        let image =  UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size, format: format).image { rendererContext in
            color.setFill()
            rendererContext.fill(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
        }
        return image
    }   

}
```

Then, instead of:

```
progressView.tintColor = .red
```

use:

```
let img = UIImage.withColor(.red)
progressView.progressImage = img
```

---

Not fully tested, but to avoid the need to change existing code, you might also try:

```
extension UIProgressView {
    open override var tintColor: UIColor! {
        didSet {
            let img = UIImage.withColor(tintColor)
            progressImage = img
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can keep your existing `progressView.tintColor = .red`

Comment: Thank you it's working but still didn't get that tintColour issue. :D

Comment: This indeed seems to solve the bug. However, now it seems the corner-radius of the UIProgressView is gone... Might be better to use a basic UIView after all and fix some simple code, at least then you can make it higher instead of that super small fixed height of the UIProgressView